# Switch case only displaying the first key in an array

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

Good afternoon,

What I'm trying to accomplish with this script is a program that returns three relevant links based on selected areas of interest. On the first page is a form where I use `<input type="checkbox">` with the `name` attribute set to `interests[]` to store the users selections in an array. The code block after the jump is the form processing script which echoes out links if the form validates. Where I'm running into trouble is my switch case function `displaylinks();` is only displaying `interests[0]` after the form is processed even though `print_r` shows something like this

```
Array (
[0] => Web Development
[1] => Startups
[2] => Video Games
)
```

If multiple interests are selected only the one in the first position of the array is displayed. Any ideas?

```
//Success condition:: for name with interests
if($_POST["fullname"] != "" && (isset($_POST['interests']))) {
echo '<div class="interests">';     
displayLinks();//Links are only displayed when the form validates successfully
echo '<a  href="/Exercise1">Return to start.</a>';          
    echo '</div>';  
} 

function displayLinks(){

$interests = $_POST['interests'];
print_r($interests);//just to see whats in the array for debugging

switch (TRUE) {
    case in_array("Design", $interests):
         echo "<h2>Design</h2>";
         echo '<p><a href="http://dribbble.com" target="_blank">Dribbble</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://news.layervault.com" target="_blank">Designer News</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://beta.psdboard.com/" target="_blank">PSDboard</a></p>';
         break; 
    case in_array("Web Development", $interests):
         echo "<h2>Web Development</h2>";
         echo '<p><a href="http://jqapi.com/" target="_blank">jQuery API</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/" target="_blank">Google API Library</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/" target="_blank">Mozilla Developer Network</a></p>';
         break; 
    case in_array("Startups", $interests):
         echo "<h2>Startups</h2>";
         echo '<p><a href="http://news.ycombinator.com" target="_blank">Hacker News</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://andrewchen.co/" target="_blank">@andrewchen</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://techcrunch.com/" target="_blank">Tech Crunch</a></p>';
         break; 
    case in_array("Video Games", $interests):
         echo "<h2>Video Games</h2>";
         echo '<p><a href="http://twitch.tv" target="_blank">TwitchTV</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://www.giantbomb.com/" target="_blank">Giant Bomb</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://tap-repeatedly.com" target="_blank">Tap Repeatedly</a></p>';
         break;                     
    case in_array("Online Magazines", $interests):
         echo "<h2>Online Magazines</h2>";
         echo '<p><a href="https://medium.com/" target="_blank">Medium</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://svbtle.com" target="_blank">Svbtle</a><br/>';
         echo '<a href="http://explorecreaterepeat.com/" target="_blank">Explore Create Repeat</a></p>';
}
}//End display links function
```

edit: In response to the first answer

> this is for a homework assignment and the rubric gives more points for using a switch case.

Comment: Here is a good starting point to learn about switch in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php), as they say do your homework. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool.  The `switch` statement is designed to only select one condition.  What you want is a whole string of individual `if` blocks.

```
if (in_array("Design", $interests)) {
     echo "<h2>Design</h2>";
     echo '<p><a href="http://dribbble.com" target="_blank">Dribbble</a><br/>';
     echo '<a href="http://news.layervault.com" target="_blank">Designer News</a><br/>';
     echo '<a href="http://beta.psdboard.com/" target="_blank">PSDboard</a></p>';
}

if (in_array("Web Development", $interests)) {
     echo "<h2>Web Development</h2>";
     echo '<p><a href="http://jqapi.com/" target="_blank">jQuery API</a><br/>';
     echo '<a href="https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/" target="_blank">Google API Library</a><br/>';
     echo '<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/" target="_blank">Mozilla Developer Network</a></p>';
}

// etc...
```

Comment: I'm aware of this but this is for a homework assignment and the rubric gives more points for using a switch case.

Comment: In that case, don't use `in_array`.  Iterate through each element in your array and use a `switch` statement on the element where your cases are string literals *eg* `case "Design":`...

Comment: When I use the string literal like this only the first case is executed and the others seem to be ignored when multiple options are selected.

Comment: The value you supply to `switch` is the value you are testing.  Let's say you have `$interest` which is the current element in the array `$interests` (because you are iterating through with `foreach`), then you would `switch($interest)`.

Comment: edit: nevermind, this worked! thanks!

`print_r` shows values in the array but nothing is being echoed if I apply your last comment.